# how to get the Subtraction total between 2dates in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have in my database 2 tables each one contains a date and a total and I want to get the  Subtraction of this totals between 2 dates. Help plz

Comment: would you please show me some codes? and what like of output you want?

Comment: I have 2 tables : recette_etrants{ $table->string('descriptionEntrant');
            $table->integer('MontantEntrant');
            $table->date('dateEntrant');} and recette_sortants{$table->string('descriptionSortant');
            $table->integer('MontantSortant');
            $table->date('dateSortant');} and I want to get montatantSortant-montantEntrant between 2 dates selected

Comment: please put the comment text in your question text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you data tables structure need some improvements (primary key, relations ...)

any way ... you can get the montatantSortant-montantEntrant between 2 dates
using [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)   and [join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

by joining the two table using their dates column you can get the result you want ...

```
$date1=getDate1();
$date2=getDate2();

 $values = DB::table('recette_etrants')->join('recette_sortants', 'recette_sortants.dateSortant', '=', 'recette_etrants.dateEntrant')->
        whereBetween('recette_etrants.dateEntrant', array($date1, $date2))
            ->selectRaw('(recette_sortants.montatantSortant -recette_etrants.montantEntrant) as result')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, plaise how I can show this $values in input type text after selecting 2 dates and  clicking on a button in view